# Proper way to calculate a selection of GRIB2 data points?

Tags: grib, grib-2, wgrib2

I have a GRIB2 file that I have successfully parsed and got an array of temperatures for a specific latitude and longitude. What would be the proper way to convert this array to a single value? I wasn't sure if taking the average might be the correct way to do this, so I wanted to double-check.